# PHP count all elements in an array

Tags: php

I'm unable to get the sizeof/count of the pages_article array in the $total_count variable. I tried $total_count = count($this->pages_articles); and it's not able to count all the elements in the pages_articles array. I tried sizeof as well and it's the same problem. There's 8 elements in the array and when I do echo/print, it displays 0.

```
  <?php
  class Pagination {
  public $current_page;
  public $per_page;
  public $total_count;
  public $pages_articles;

  public function __construct($page=1, $per_page=20, $total_count=0) {
 $this->current_page = (int)$page;
 $this->per_page = (int)$per_page;
 $this->total_count = (int)$total_count;
 $this->pages_articles=array(
  '<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/CmU3tnl.jpg"></div>',
  '<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/TDdxS9H.png"></div>',
  '<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/39rpmwB.jpg"></div>',
  '<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1lBZQ1B.png"></div>',
  '<div class="article-loop"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Y5Ld4Qfh.jpg"></div>',
  '<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8HumESY.jpg"></div>',
  '<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/CqCZBvk.png"></div>',
  '<div class="article-loop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wQVPRVp.png"></div>');
  }

  public function offset() {
return ($this->current_page - 1) * $this->per_page;
   }
  public function total_pages() {
//$this->total_count=sizeof($this->pages_articles);
return ceil($this->total_count/$this->per_page);
   }
  public function previous_page() {
return $this->current_page - 1;
   } 
  public function next_page() {
return $this->current_page + 1;
   }
  public function has_previous_page() {
return $this->previous_page() >= 1 ? true : false;
   }
  public function has_next_page() {
return $this->next_page() <= $this->total_pages() ? true : false;
   }
  }
  $page = !empty($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
  $per_page = 3;
  $total_count=8;
  $pagination = new Pagination($page, $per_page, $total_count);
  ?>

  <html>
  <body>
  <div>
<?php
    $i = $pagination->offset()  ;
    $limit = $pagination->per_page;
    while($i<$pagination->total_count && $limit>0) {
        echo $pagination->pages_articles[$i]."<br>";
        $i++;
        $limit--;
    }
      ?>
  </div>
  <ul>
      <?php
    if($pagination->has_previous_page()) {
        echo '<li style="display:inline"><a  href="index.php?page='.$pagination->previous_page().'">&laquo;</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li style="display:inline" class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>';
    }
    for($i=1; $i<=$pagination->total_pages(); $i++) {
        echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$i.'"><li style="display:inline; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px">'.$i.'</li></a>';
    }
    if($pagination->has_next_page()) {
        echo '<li style="display:inline"><a href="index.php?page='.$pagination->next_page().'">&raquo;</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li style="display:inline" class="disabled"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>';
    }
   ?>
  </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Use `exit(var_dump($this->pages_articles)` one line before your count to make sure the pages_articles has something, did you try?

Comment: I think there might be a problem to getting data in `public function total_pages() {}` So first try to print array in this function.

Comment: It works if I print it in the total_pages function. I created a new variable $total in this function and assigned count($this->pages_articles); I then tried to assign this variable to $total_count and it still displays 0.

Comment: This code works fine as it is. Works In the sense that the count calculation is fine and it returns the correct number instead of `0`. Its the unnecessarily complicated nature of this code that is confusing. https://eval.in/827679

Comment: I see, but I want to be able to assign the total number of elements in the array to the $total_count variable. Is this possible with the way the code is structured?

Comment: Why not have the constructor end with ``$this->total_count = sizeof( $this->pages_articles );``

Comment: @kmoser that works beautifully. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE)`

Comment: OP said he tried that already. Read the question in full, then get clarification in the comments

Comment: I don't see anywhere that is says he tried COUNT_RECURSIVE. Do you?

Comment: I have tried that as well and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you add a var_dump of your array?

Comment: This is what that prints to the screen. array(8) { [0]=> string(74) "
" [1]=> string(74) "
" [2]=> string(74) "
" [3]=> string(74) "
" [4]=> string(76) "
" [5]=> string(74) "
" [6]=> string(74) "
" [7]=> string(74) "
" }

Comment: I don't see the URL strings in your array output as defined in your original code.